# Custom navigation links in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

In my project I'm using `rails_admin` gem to get admin panel functionality. I have on issue with this gem. How can I add custom links to navigation header? By default there are two links: `Home` and `Dashboard`.

[image]

Comment: [https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation)?

Comment: I want to change links in header. I do not find any way do it through rails_admin config. I will probably override navigation partial.

Answer (score 1):

Take necessary files from here:
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/app/views/layouts/rails_admin

And put them under `app/views/layouts/rails_admin`, then change to whatever